# how to change img class with multiple div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tampermonkey

I am very new to tampermonkey and javascript in general. I wanted to change certain images (yes, multiple images) in a webpage which are under 3 different div classes. However, within the div class, all the three images are under the same img class. Given below are the inspect element codes for all the 3 images.

```
    <div class="Class1"><img class="same" onerror="this.errored=true;" src="imgURL1"></div>
    <div class="Class2"><img class="same" onerror="this.errored=true;" src="imgURL2"></div> 
    <div class="Class3"><img class="same" onerror="this.errored=true;" src="imgURL3"></div>
```

How do I change each one separately? Thanks in advance

Comment: JavaScript you mean? Right?

Comment: JavaScript is not Java. What have you tried so far? Please show us your efforts. Also,please revise your question as it seems a bit unclear.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I meant JavaScript. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 4):

Even image class is same but parent div class is different. So you can access it through div like:

```
$('.Class1 img') // will provide you ist image
$('.Class2 img') // will provide you 2nd image
```

You can change image src like

```
$('.Class1 img').attr('src','') // add image src to change image
```

Comment: @KevinBell you have mistake in your html too. you haven't enclose <img tag. Also on error you have quotes on one side

Comment: @Rupal I've fixed these. However, it is still not working. The image is not changing. I have written code to change text in the same page and it's working. Only the image is not changing. Is there another way of doing it?

Comment: @Rupal Oh sorry, I found my mistake. I accidentally forgot to put the dot before the class name. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KevinBell always accept answer if you think that helps you so that others can also get benefit in future